# How to properly set environment variables in Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, environment-variables

I can't figure out how to set environment variables properly, even though I tried to follow https://wiki.debian.org/EnvironmentVariables.

I've added this to `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_profile ]; then
    . ~/.bash_profile
fi
```

It seemed logical to me to comment these lines in `~/.profile` after doing that:

```
# if running bash
# if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
#    # include .bashrc if it exists
#    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
#   . "$HOME/.bashrc"
#    fi
#fi
```

Now when I open a terminal, variables in `~/.profile` and `~/.bash_profile` are correctly exported.

How do I make the variables in `~/.profile` available for applications I launch through XFCE menu? I know it isn't the case because if I launch `gpodder` from a terminal, it does what I want, ie. it detects `$GPODDER_HOME` which is set in my `.profile`, but this doesn't happen when I launch it "graphically".

Comment: Your display manager doesn't source `.profile` at startup? You could use `/etc/environment` (and `~/.pam_environment`) for variables other than `PATH`.

Comment: `~/.pam_environment` didn't help. :(
Isn't it 'dirty' to modify /etc/environment for my podcast download folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `man xsession`:

> `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/40x11-common_xsessionrc`
>
> Source global environment variables.  This script will source anything in `$HOME/.xsessionrc`  if  the  file is present. This allows the user to set global environment variables for their X session, such as locale information.

Comment: This looks better than what I did. I'll test it later and approve your answer if it works.

Comment: `. /home/nicoco/.profile` in `. /home/nicoco/.xsessionrc` was what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I finally added a `profile.desktop` file in `~/.config/autostart` that looks like this:

```
~/.config/autostart$ cat profile.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=0.9.4
Type=Application
Name=profile
Comment=
Exec=/bin/bash /home/nicoco/.profile
OnlyShowIn=XFCE;
StartupNotify=false
Terminal=false
Hidden=false
```

This is the only workaround I found that doesn't involve modifying files as root.